# Pandas: Counting different elements in columns of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp':[13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000112,4707821000114, 5707821000114, 5707821000114, 5707821000114],
       'name_dep': ['DIONILSO MATEUS MARCON', 'JOSE AUGUSTO ROSA', 'LUCIO ANTONIO MOSQUINI', 'DIEGO ALVES','BRUNO HENRIQUE', 'GABRIEL BARBOSA', 'DIONILSO MATEUS MARCON', 'BRUNO HENRIQUE']
       })
```

How do I account for how much different elements I have in each column?
Ex.: In the 'name_dep' column the names 'DIONILSO MATEUS MARCON' and 'BRUNO HENRIQUE' appear twice, but will only be counted once. So the expected output for number of different elements of that column would be 6.

Comment: Add an expected output please.

Comment: `df.nunique()` ??

Comment: You want `df['name_dep'].value_counts()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the unique elements of a column with:

```
df['id_emp'].unique()
```

And the number of unique elements with:

```
df['id_emp'].nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.nunique()`

this method return the number of unique item